# Formation of wave ripple fields (in sand)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, water

I've read a few articles about wave ripple fields:

- https://www.coastalwiki.org/wiki/Wave_ripple_formation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave-formed_ripple

and a few others.

However, those two articles seem to contradict each other, and also do not explain how ripples form, but how they sustain once they are formed (and do this in a rather precarious or unclear way in my humble opinion.)

The idea that they share is that there is some circular/orbital flow of water. Wikipedia locates it (in the image at least) in the trough; the Coastalwiki locates two (not one) below the crest, and assigns the cause for the formation of the ripple to some turbulence that I can't really see how it appears.

There is a great video from MIT showing [how they form from flat sand here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uY2QdZLLRP8). I've searched for any article from the authors, but there isn't any conceptual explanation of how one would imagine the flow lines that produce this phenomenon.

I've downloaded some fluid mechanics books but I'm mostly searching for a conceptual explanation, maybe using flow lines and a few equations, rather than solving many difficult differential equations.

Any explanations or just pointers to good sources you may have found are very welcome.